# Limited file information from contenttype file

Tags: file, twig, bolt-cms

I've implemented a content type which includes a `file` field.

```
articles:
  fields:
    title:
      type: text
    body:
      type: html
    attachment:
      type: file
```

When I go to output the information in a template I access the file with:

```
record.attachment
```

However this only provides me with the path of the file and nothing else.

**Question:**
Is it possible to get the filesize and a human friendly filename from the record object? Or do I have to create a Twig function in an extension to do this?

**An alternative?**
I guess the alternative would be to create a `files` contenttype with fields for name, size, etc. Then relate this back to my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd opt to do this in a twig filter. If you use an image we already have a built in filter do get this information `{{imageinfo(fieldname)}}` will return an array of information.

Logically a similar function `fileinfo` could get the necessary info if all you are interested in is the metadata about a file.

If you do want to store additional content information that can't be discerned via a php function then you will need to use the related content type idea.